# parsing email contents from poplib with email module (PYTHON)

Tags: python, email, python-3.x, pop3

**PYTHON VERSION == 3.5**

code:

```
import getpass, poplib, email
Mailbox = poplib.POP3_SSL('pop.googlemail.com', '995')
Mailbox.user("email_here@gmail.com")
Mailbox.pass_('password_here')
numMessages = len(Mailbox.list()[1])
for i in range(numMessages):
    info  = b" ".join(Mailbox.retr(i+1)[1])
    msg = email.message_from_bytes(info)
    print(msg.keys())
```

output:

```
['MIME-Version']
['MIME-Version']
['MIME-Version']
['Delivered-To']
['Delivered-To']
['Delivered-To']
['Delivered-To']
['Delivered-To']
['Delivered-To']
['Delivered-To']
['Delivered-To']
```

the output isn't correct because there should be more fields from the 
`msg` other than `"MIME-Version"` and `"Delivered-To"` I thought

`email.message_from_bytes()` parses the contents of a byte string

is `msg` not a byte string?

the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/poplib.html#pop3-example) recommend this:

```
M = poplib.POP3('localhost')
M.user(getpass.getuser())
M.pass_(getpass.getpass())
numMessages = len(M.list()[1])
for i in range(numMessages):
    for j in M.retr(i+1)[1]:
        print(j)
```

Is there a way to parse the returned message using the email module?
so we can store the email details. like sender, body, header etc.

Answer (score 3):

the answer turned out to be fairly easy

```
import getpass, poplib, email
Mailbox = poplib.POP3_SSL('pop.googlemail.com', '995')
Mailbox.user("email_here@gmail.com")
Mailbox.pass_('password_here')
numMessages = len(Mailbox.list()[1])
for i in range(numMessages):
    raw_email  = b"\n".join(Mailbox.retr(i+1)[1])
    parsed_email = email.message_from_bytes(raw_email)
    print(parsed_email.keys())
```

instead of joining  `raw_email` with a space just join it by a `\n` and the `email` module can parse the fields correctly:

also an a awesome thing about using the `email` module
is when you call `email.message_from_bytes()` the output returned is 
a `dict`

so you access the fields like this:

```
raw_email  = b"\n".join(Mailbox.retr(i+1)[1])
parsed_email = email.message_from_bytes(raw_email)
print(parsed_email["header"])
```

but what if the field doesn't exist?:

```
raw_email  = b"\n".join(Mailbox.retr(i+1)[1])
parsed_email = email.message_from_bytes(raw_email)
print(parsed_email["non-existent field"])
```

the above code will return `None` and not throw a `KeyError`