# Issues with finding something in a list

Tags: python, parsing, gmail

I have a program that retrieves messages from my email (via POP) and I want to retrieve the subject of the emails, I'm using this:

```
import poplib
from email import parser
pop_srvr = poplib.POP3_SSL('pop.gmail.com')
pop_srvr.user('username')
pop_srvr.pass_('password')
messages = [pop_srvr.retr(i) for i in range(1, len(pop_srvr.list()[1]) + 1)]
messages = [b"\n".join(mssg[1]) for mssg in messages]
messages = [parser.Parser().parsestr(mssg) for mssg in messages]
for message in messages:
  print (message['subject'])
  print (message['body'])
pop_srvr.quit()
```

but when I run it I get this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Yousef/Desktop/parser proto.py", line 11, in <module>
messages = [parser.Parser().parsestr(mssg) for mssg in messages]
File "C:/Users/Yousef/Desktop/parser proto.py", line 11, in <listcomp>
messages = [parser.Parser().parsestr(mssg) for mssg in messages]
File "C:\Users\Yousef\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-
32\lib\email\parser.py", line 68, in parsestr
return self.parse(StringIO(text), headersonly=headersonly)
TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not bytes
```

someone plz tell me what I'm doing wrong...

Answer (score 0):

```
It seems linke  poplib.POP3_SSL module returns bytes object.

You probably need to change following :


    ["\n".join(mssg[1]) for mssg in messages]

 to

    [b"\n".join(mssg[1]) for mssg in messages]
```

I found that `email` module has `message_from_bytes` function. Have you tried using it? I may be misunderstood in below code. Please verify at your side :

```
import email

messages = [pop_srvr.retr(i) for i in range(1, len(pop_srvr.list()[1]) + 1)]
messages = [b"\n".join(mssg[1]) for mssg in messages]
messages = [email.message_from_bytes(mssg) for mssg in messages]
for message in messages:
  print (message['subject'])
  print (message['body'])
pop_srvr.quit()
```

More on : [parsing email contents from poplib with email module (PYTHON)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35679338/parsing-email-contents-from-poplib-with-email-module-python)

Comment: What was error. Can you please edit post error above?

Comment: messages = [parser.Parser().parsestr(mssg) for mssg in messages], it says return self.parse(StringIO(text), headersonly=headersonly)
TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not bytes

Comment: I have updated the code with ```message_from_bytes``` method. Have you tried that? More on : https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.parser.html#email.message_from_bytes

Comment: I removed the str in [parser.Parser().parsestr(mssg) for mssg in messages] and for some reason i just get nothing in the console

Comment: I am using ```message_from_bytes``` method. Have you implemented that?

Comment: I've never used it before so I honestly don't know how to implement it.

Comment: I have attached the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35679338/parsing-email-contents-from-poplib-with-email-module-python

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried casting it to a string?

`messages = [parser.Parser().parsestr(str(mssg)) for mssg in messages]`

It may result in an incorrect string, but this way you can check if `mssg` is indeed a bytes-like. If the error disappears, you can cast it in a way that works for your program.

Comment: When I used this, No errors occur, I just get a bunch of Nones on my console.

Comment: My guess is that `mssg` is a Nonetype. Casting it to a string results in "None". Can you print the type and value of `mssg` before this line? `print(type(mssg)); print(mssg)` ( in two seperate lines so that if the second print errors, you can still see the type).

Comment: I can't print mssg because it's just a temporary variable in the loop, it just tells me 'mssg' is not defined

Comment: You can access it outside of the loop by referring to the first element of the list `print(type(messages[0]))`